# Calling async function with `function().Wait()` works, but `async function()` crashes

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm calling a 3rd party library from my C# code, and have found that `ctx.CreateSiteAsync(communicationSiteInfo).Wait();` works well, while `await ctx.CreateSiteAsync(communicationSiteInfo);` causes the application to crash. As `.Wait()` to the best of my knowledge causes the thread to block, I'm interested inn getting the `await` approach to work. 
Here an extract from my code to put the above calls in context:

```
        public async Task createSite(string base_url, SiteConfig siteConfig) {
           using(var ctx = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(base_url, this.applicationId, this.applicationSecret)) {
           ctx.Load(ctx.Web, p => p.Title);
           ctx.ExecuteQuery();

           CommunicationSiteCollectionCreationInformation communicationSiteInfo = new CommunicationSiteCollectionCreationInformation {
              Title = siteConfig.title,
              Url = siteConfig.url,
              SiteDesign = siteConfig.siteDesign,
              Description = siteConfig.description,
              Owner = siteConfig.ownerEmailAddress
           };

          try {
           // This works: ctx.CreateSiteAsync(communicationSiteInfo).Wait();
           await ctx.CreateSiteAsync(communicationSiteInfo);

          } catch....
```

If I'm not mistaking, the function I'm calling it this one: [ClientContextExtensions.cs](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/Extensions/ClientContextExtensions.cs#L778).
I'm pretty new to C#, so perhaps the reason for the application crashing is obvious, but I can't see why the `await` wouldn't work, as the function I'm calling has `async Task` in it's definition.

EDIT: The weird thing regarding the exception is that the application simply crashes, and the `catch` clause is never reached. I don't know, but maybe this has something to do with threading or context or something in that the exception thrown in the async function call are not returned to the current thread. The application crashes on the `await ctx.CreateSiteAsync(communicationSiteInfo);` call.

EDIT 2: It looks as though I can simplify the issue at hand, but using this as an example instead:

```
 public async Task StartMessageQueuePollAsync()
    {
        while (true)
        {
           await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false); 

            }
```

This causes the code to crash on `await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);`. If is instead use `Task.Delay(1000).Wait()`, the code works as expected.

Comment: Where does the exception happen? What is the error?

Comment: @vendettamit, I updated the post with some more data. See "EDIT".

Comment: Check your windows event logs there should be an exception logged.

Comment: Thanks @vendettamit. I took a look at "Windows Logs > Application" in the Event viewer, but didn't find any entries related to my application.

Comment: Regarding the second example, how do you call the `StartMessageQueuePollAsync` method?

Answer (score 1):

I see your answer, but I don't think that's the root cause. It's perfectly fine to use `static async Task Main()`, as long as your project is using C# 7.0 or higher (when that was introduced). If changing that (and making everything else synchronous, as you'd have to after removing `async`) made the symptom go away, then that means that somewhere along your call stack, you were missing an `await`.

For example, [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aICXZs) works just fine:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello.");
        await Pause();
        Console.WriteLine("All done");
    }

    public static async Task Pause() {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Done pausing");
    }
}
```

But if you remove the `await` in `Main`, then the application would end before "Done pausing" is printed. This is because `async` methods run synchronously at first, but *return* at the first `await` that acts on an incomplete `Task`. (`Pause()` returns a `Task` when it hits `await Task.Delay(1000)` - *before* the waiting is completed)

So if you don't `await` an `async` method, then your code will just move on to the next line before the work is done. Sometimes you actually want this, but often not.

Since it otherwise runs synchronously, replacing the `await` with `.Wait()` would halt the thread and the method would not return, making it suddenly "work".

In your code, that means that either you weren't awaiting `createSite()` or weren't awaiting whatever called the method that called `createSite()`, etc.

Microsoft has a series of very well-written articles about asynchronous articles that are worth reading. Start here: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments on my initial post. I got it working now, and believe it's because of I defined the `Main` method to be async, like this:
`static async Task Main()`.